# Is there an Eleasticsearch equivalent for INSERT INTO SELECT?

Tags: elasticsearch

From an index containing apache log entries, I want to write a query that will return a list of ip numbers. Next, I want to store that list of ip numbers in a new document.

I understand this can be easily achieved in 2 steps with a search and an index statement, but since the list of ip numbers can be very large, I'm looking for a way to achieve this in elasticsearch without having to actually send the list back to the client and use it as input to a separate index statement.

Is there a way to do this server-side, similar to an INSERT INTO SELECT from the sql world?

Comment: Looking for something similar. A materialized view or something that polls ES and feeds data back into it.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know , there is no such functionalities as of now in Elasticsearch.