# What are limitations on Elasticsearch that not allow to use another query results as parameters (SQL equivalent IN / EXISTS)

Tags: elasticsearch

This has been raised in [What is the best way to create a subset of my data in Elasticsearch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33503808/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-a-subset-of-my-data-in-elasticsearch#comment54794857_33503808) and has been bugging me for a while too.

I'd like to know what are (*technical?*) limitations that wouldn't let you run something like this?

```
POST /logstash-*/_search
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "terms": {
          "client_ip": {
            "by_query": {
              "field": "client_ip",
              "query": {
                "term": {
                  "request_page": "razor.html"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So this would run a nested query, that'd find all `client_ip` that have `"request_page": "razor.html"` and bring back all records that have this IP address.

SQL equivalent would be something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Apache.Logs AS L1
WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM Apache.Logs AS L2
        WHERE L2.client_ip = L1.client_ip
            AND L2.request_page = 'razor.html'
        );
```

Or rather an IN clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM Apache.Logs AS L1
WHERE L1.client_ip IN (
        SELECT L2.client_ip
        FROM Apache.Logs AS L2
        WHERE L2.request_page = 'razor.html'
        );
```

I know that this can be done in Application using Application Side Joins.

If this has already been asked/requested - please provide a link, I couldn't find this by myself.

Comment: Are you sure you can actually create such type of query?

Comment: I know I can't create such a query. My question is what are limitations preventing from doing it,

Comment: I guess the question is can we use output of a query as input to another query. Check this: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/use-output-of-one-query-in-as-input-in-another/27481 and

Comment: It still doesn't answer it, unfortunately. *You cannot currently do this.*. There's no real explanation and I'm interested in that.

Comment: I agree on there is no reason on why this can't be done. All I could think of is(if logical) is when a search is executed, it goes to each shard and then searched(search phase), goes back to master and all shards are asked to return the result(fetch phase). Here there is no shard search for the inner query, only a search result would be in memory(which ought to be maintained by master).  Sounds bit vague but who knows.. :-)

Comment: your thoughts @Evaldas

Comment: It can be done on application side. So I just wonder what's stopping service from doing that. Perhaps someone will spot it.

Comment: how on application side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is actually an [open issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/6769) about this very subject. There is some "join" support inside Lucene so nothing would technically prevent ES from leveraging it... BUT... the reasons mentioned in that issue are mainly performance-related, i.e. doing JOINs in a distributed environment such as Elasticsearch would perform very badly as a lot of network chatter would take place.

ES folks advocate for leveraging the parent/child relationship whenever 1-N JOIN support is needed.

Another option that can fill some specific needs is the [`terms` lookup mechanism](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html#query-dsl-terms-lookup), which provides a way to do a real JOIN within a single index or between two indices.

And finally, building upon the above-mentioned "terms lookup mechanism", up-and-coming is a pull request for introducing [a JOIN filter](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/3278) (that will provide support for exactly the kind of queries in your question), but it's currently stalled because of some conflicts that need to be resolved before merging.

So it seems that the main reason for not providing JOIN support (i.e. performance) has been solved after all, now I guess it's just a matter of time.

Comment: I wasn't avare of terms lookup mechanism. But this seem to be very useful. Thanks for great answer!

Comment: Wow. this is great. Even I didnt know the terms lookup mechanism. Thanks @Val :-)

Comment: right now the search is ID based. Wish id could be replaced by query. :D

Comment: This is coming. See the ["JOIN filter"](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/3278) link in my answer

Comment: Great to hear about the JOIN filter. For now though, if we use the terms lookup mechanism, we need to get the terms array from a single document. Any idea how we can create that document without pulling all the data over the line? I asked this earlier here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33497028/is-there-an-eleasticsearch-equivalent-for-insert-into-select